# Access: Column with data split by semicolon into many-to-many relation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database built by total morons. They did not use any relationships at all and put everything into one table. They asked me if I could extract some useful informations out of it and clean it up.

Say I have a table called "MEMBERS", one of the columns in that table is "Email addresses".

In this column all the emailadresses are split by semicolons, so a possible input could be:

*lala@lalaland.com; ronny@ronnywebs.com; tomato@pulpketch.up*

whilst another could be just

*irule@theworld.com*

What I want to do now is make a new table "EMAILS" and a table "EMAIL-MEMBERS", as I need a many-to-many relation (members can have the same parents, so the same email adresses, members also can have 4 emails).

The only data I got is the messed up email column. I have to do this not only for emails, but for phone numbers aswell, but I guess that doesn't really matter as the method will be the same.

Anyone got an idea about how to create a custom query or macro which *splits* a column into multiple new records in another table, whilst creating new ones to indicate the relation and with the EMAILS table having a unique email column (so no insert if the email already exists)? Manual is also not an option. It's a member database containing about 4000 records. Hell no.

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is a VBA loop that will parse the data as it's read.  I'd write out the code but I'm pressed for time, but it really shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: use an array and  split(email_col, ";") to split the emails use the array and member id to insert new records